Window part identification
My balance for a vertical sliding window broke.
I got a new pair, replaced them but then found out there is a plastic part on the window that is broken.
It's on the top corner, in the middle of the frame that catches onto the balance when sliding it up or down.
Can anyone tell me what it is? I can't find out the name to get a new one. Window part that broken

Window parts are proprietary for the manufacturer. The name of the part is given by the manufacturer. For this reason knowing the name of the part is a crapshoot.  If you know the manufacturer of the window, possibly get in touch with them.

If you can get an intact part out of the window, you may be able to check at SWISCO to see if they have a replacement part.

Thanks I will give them a shout and see if I can. Winters coming hopefully getting it fixed up soon.
If I get the part identified ill give an update for others that may have this issue.
